# Problems in upgrading JSyn related programs

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, upgrade, jsyn

I am trying to upgrade some online synth applications made with the old JSyn plugin .

Initially the former programmer sent me the .jar file of the synth application which was more or less not useful .

I asked for the project files so that I can perform the upgrade.
I received a folder with an .src ending which when I open has multiple subfolders that end up in .java files that I can edit .

Now the files are at least editable but both Netbeans and Eclipse can't see any of the folders as a project file so reprogramming and understanding the structure of the program is kind of a nuisance .

It would be helpful if anybody explained to me what is happening and/or how to solve that problem .

Answer (score 0):

You can build a new JSyn JAR file using the source code on GitHub at:
    https://github.com/philburk/jsyn

The GitHub repo has a .project file for Eclipse so you can open it directly in Eclipse. Then add the JSyn project to your own project.

1. Right click on your project name in Eclipse.
2. Select "Build Path > Configure Build Path..."
3. Click on "Projects" Tab
4. Add the JSyn Project